# Windows XP recovery console locks CD drive, even after restart!

Tags: windows-xp, user-experience, recovery-console

Whenever I use my Windows XP SP2 installation CD that came with my Dell computer to use the recovery console, I have a problem.

I understand that it's a bad idea to remove the CD while the recovery console is in use, because recovery console needs access to files on the CD.  It makes sense that the recovery console locks the CD drive.  Pressing the eject button on the CD drive has no effect.  That's fine.

However, after I type `exit` to quit the recovery console and restart the computer, the CD drive remains locked.  Pressing the eject button on the CD drive **still** has no effect.  That's not fine.

I am forced to power the computer off with the power button, and then power it back on, just to eject the CD.  Sometimes I'm a bad guy and use a paperclip to eject the CD instead of hard power-cycling the machine again.

Is this by design, or have I found a bug?

- If this is by design, why was it designed this way?
- If I have found a bug, where or to whom do I report it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely a bug in the software on the Dell CD, wherein it never releases the lock from the drive.  Doing a full power cycle will reset that bit of the drive.  You can report it to Dell, but I'd be willing to wager that they know already.

Comment: Report it anyway. They obviously need prodding.